# Changing Manintine's button component's font family in NextJS 13

Tags: button, next.js13, font-family, google-fonts, mantine

I am currently developing an app using NextJS 13 and Mantine. I gotten Mantine to work with NextJS but seem to have run into an issuse with Mantine where I am unable to change the font family of some components. I am tring to do this using NextJS's optimized fonts (google fonts). Everything seems to be fine while im in development mode but then when I build the application and then view it, the font family I specified was not applied. This has been the case for the Button, Text, and Title components. Has anybody encountered this issue and if so, how did you resolve it?

I tried using NextJS's classNames method on the Mantine components while specifying the font family via the component props, fontFamily, sx and the createStyles method, but that did not seem to take.